# How to write 'I' if two columns are having similar values in pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe is like this:

```
            RS                 AS                    IS
F1  [F1, F2, F3, F4, F5]      [F1]                  [F1]
F2  [F2, F3, F5]          [F1, F2, F3, F5]      [F5, F3, F2]
F3  [F2, F3, F4, F5]      [F1, F2, F3, F5]      [F5, F3, F2]
F4  [F4]                  [F1, F3, F4, F5]          [F4]
F5  [F2, F3, F4, F5]      [F1, F2, F3, F5]      [F5, F3, F2]
```

Output I need:

```
            RS                 AS                    IS          Level
F1  [F1, F2, F3, F4, F5]      [F1]                  [F1]     
F2  [F2, F3, F5]          [F1, F2, F3, F5]      [F5, F3, F2]       I
F3  [F2, F3, F4, F5]      [F1, F2, F3, F5]      [F5, F3, F2]       
F4  [F4]                  [F1, F3, F4, F5]          [F4]           I
F5  [F2, F3, F4, F5]      [F1, F2, F3, F5]      [F5, F3, F2]
```

The logic is very simple. If RS and IS is having similar values then write `I` in Level column.
I am using the following code but looks like it doesn't work.

```
if df['RS'].any() == df['IS'].any():
df['Level'] = 'I'
```

Also need to drop the entire row having level 'I' from original Dataframe after above method is implemented. like this

```
            RS                 AS                    IS
F1  [F1, F2, F3, F4, F5]      [F1]                  [F1]
F3  [F2, F3, F4, F5]      [F1, F2, F3, F5]      [F5, F3, F2]
F5  [F2, F3, F4, F5]      [F1, F2, F3, F5]      [F5, F3, F2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your lists to `set` and then comparing for equality to get which rows have the same elements, then assign the value.  The example below ignores your middle column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'RS':
    [[1,2,3,4,5],
     [2,3,5],
     [2,3,4,5],
     [4],
     [2,3,4,5]],
    'IS':
    [[1],
     [5,3,2],
     [5,3,2],
     [4],
     [5,3,2]]})

ix = df.RS.apply(set) == df.IS.apply(set)
df['Level'] = ''
df.loc[ix, 'Level'] = 'I'

df:
# returns:
             RS         IS Level
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]        [1]
      [2, 3, 5]  [5, 3, 2]     I
   [2, 3, 4, 5]  [5, 3, 2]
            [4]        [4]     I
   [2, 3, 4, 5]  [5, 3, 2]
```

If you need to drop the rows where `I` would be assigned; you don't actually need to assign `I`, just use:

```
ix = df.RS.apply(set) == df.IS.apply(set)
df.loc[~ix]
```

Comment: Many Thanks! Kindly check the entire question. I have edit the question

Comment: Updated my answer as well